# PHP regex preg_grep change string path

Tags: php, regex

I have array:

```
$array = array(
    "C:/path/something1/something2/dir",
    "C:/path1/something/something2/dir2\nextdir",
    "C:/path2/something/dir2\nextdir\next",
    "C:/path/something3/something6/something7/dir5\nextdir2\next"
);
```

All that is before the last sign "/" with him to disappear.

I want something like that:

```
$array = array(
    "dir",
    "dir2\nextdir",
    "dir2\nextdir\next",
    "dir5\nextdir2\next"
);
```

I need regex

```
$new_array = preg_grep("/regex/", $array);
```

I have no idea how to write a regex.

I dont want like that:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $e = explode("/", $val);
    $new_array[] = end($e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) does not change/replace the values, it returns the items that match the given regular expression. If you must use regex and replace the values, take a look at [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead:

```
$array = preg_replace('~.*/~', '', $array);
var_dump($array);
```

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> string(3) "dir"
  [1]=> string(12) "dir2\nextdir"
  [2]=> string(17) "dir2\nextdir\next"
  [3]=> string(18) "dir5\nextdir2\next"
}
```